# Formula for sum including threshold?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I dont know if the title is correct, but I have no idea how to nameit to be honest.

I was thinking quite some time about a formula (not VBA), but I'm giving up already.

I'm making pretty simple calculator, that will count one of the new taxes. It simply works as follows: provided liquid volume and other data the calculator is checking what value of tax is to be paid. The threshold is if the tax for 1 liter of the product is more than 1.2$, than the tax is 1.2$ **for each liter**.

The tax is generally calculated per 100 mililiters. So if per 100ml it is 5$, then 1.2$ is to be paid for 1 liter. If the product is 5l, then it is 1.2$ for each liter = 6$. However if tax per 100ml is 0.1$, then it is 1$ per 1L, and 5$ for 5L.

Another example: if tax > 1.2$ and liquid volume <= 1 liter then tax is 1.2$. However if liquid volume is >1 liter and <=2 liter, then it is 1.2 + the rest of the tax, but not more than 2.4$. If the volume is >2 but <=3, then it is 1.2 (for the first liter) + 1.2 (for the second liter) + the rest, but not more than 3.6$.

Do you have any ideas for such formula?

Comment: Sounds like a use for `MIN`

Comment: Try if formula like `=IF(Tax>=1.2,1.2,tax)`. You question is not clear.

Comment: or `=IF(Tax/Volume>=1.2,1.2,Tax/Volume)`

Comment: @Harun24HR - I'll try to be more clear: if tax > 1.2$ and liquid volume <= 1 liter then tax is 1.2$. However if liquid volume is >1 liter and <=2 liter, then it is 1.2 + the rest of the tax, but not more than 2.4$. If the volume is >2 but <=3, then it is 1.2 (for the first liter) + 1.2 (for the second liter) + the rest, but not more than 3.6$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this answers your question:
[image]

The formulas are mentioned in the last line.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, thank you!